# MySQL query with multiple inner joins on same table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables : tblBooks and tblBookMeta

tblBookMeta holds the genres of the books, and there could be more than one.

Using this query I get all the results as shown.

```
SELECT * FROM tblBooks as B inner join tblBookMeta as BM ON B.BookId = BM.BookId 

tblBooks                           tblBookMeta
BookId  Title                   |  BookMetaId   BookId  MetaName    MetaValue   
1       My Thriller Book        |  1            1       Genre       Thriller    
2       My SciFi Book           |  2            2       Genre       SciFi   
3       My Thriller SciFi Book  |  3            3       Genre       Thriller    
3       My Thriller SciFi Book  |  4            3       Genre       SciFi
```

To query the books by genre I can use this query

```
SELECT * FROM tblBooks as B
inner join tblBookMeta as BM ON B.BookId = BM.BookId 
WHERE MetaName = 'Genre' and MetaValue = 'Thriller'
```

This will return 'My Thriller Book' and 'My Thriller SciFi book. Fine

if I only want books which have both the Thriller genre and the SciFi genre, I am getting a bit stuck. I can do it like this, but I am wondering if there is a better way without sub-queries.  I may in the future want to query on more than two genres, which would create another sub query.

```
SELECT * FROM tblBooks as B
inner join tblBookMeta as BM ON B.BookId = BM.BookId 
WHERE MetaName = 'Genre' and MetaValue = 'Thriller' 
and B.BookId in (SELECT B.BookId FROM tblBooks as B
    inner join tblBookMeta as BM ON B.BookId = BM.BookId 
    WHERE MetaName = 'Genre' and MetaValue = 'SciFi')
```

Comment: There are alternate ways of achieving this (such as an extra inner join on tblBookMeta in the top level query as suggested in the answer given) but I'm not sure if they are necessarily better, either in terms of performance or readability. This is about as good as you can get I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like and check with EXPLAIN ANALYZE the better solution.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
  tblBooks as B inner join tblBookMeta as TH
    ON (B.BookId = TH.BookId and TH.MetaValue = 'Thriller')
  inner join tblBookMeta as SC
    ON (B.BookId = SC.BookId and SC.MetaValue = 'SciFi')
WHERE 
    MetaName = 'Genre'
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks - this is much cleaner